# Track sent but not received in application Application Insights

Tags: angular6, azure-application-insights

I installed version in 6.0.1 of MarkPieszak/angular-application-insights, imported the module and specified the right instrumentation key from my Application Insights App (type: node.js). A track is sent with status code 200 but I don't see any data shown in Azure.

https://github.com/MarkPieszak/angular-application-insights

[image]

Is there something I overlook here?

Comment: It may take a few minutes for the logs being shown in azure portal.

Answer (score 0):

I was expecting exceptions to show up in the Failure Panel in Azure. Now I found out that in there only server side failures are shown. After looking under Browser in Azure I found the received exceptions I was looking for. My bad.